# How can I remain in contact with my girlfriend in an Islamic way?

Tags: practical-islam, relationships, men-women

Me and my girlfriend are in an innocent relationship, but after 2 months she said we are doing it wrong: it's against the Islamic way.

How can I remain in contact with her in an Islamic way? What should I do in this situation?

Comment: You should do a Nikah and carry on your relationship just like a boyfriend and girlfriend would do.... If things work out well for you then you may go ahead and proceed with marriage.

Comment: @Qaisar Khan What are you talking about? Nikah IS marriage. There is NO intimate relationship between non-mahrams outside of marriage. Either you marry her, or you stop contacting her.

Comment: @Shadi Nikah is technically a marriage in the eyes of God, But the parties here can treat it as an "engagement" to justify their relationship. I wouldn't recommend marriage ceremony here because ceremonies could be expensive. Once they are determined to be partners for life, they may proceed on by arranging a marriage ceremony and make their Nikah publicly known. A related but slightly different incident is noted that of the Prophet PBUH and AIsha. They did Nikah when AIsha was 6 years old and then finalised it with a marriage when she became 9.

Comment: @Qaisar khan umm..i agree with ur advice but iam to young to tell parent's or i must say it simply i have fear of losing her if i tell them at this age and she needs a halal relationship..i have read somewhere that telling truth to her father or uncles or brother the truth and can be in contact with each other..so is that true..??? I will sure try to ask her brother and soon i will tell my mother..so if you don't mind is there any other way we are in a long distance relationship we first met at someones marriage

Answer (score -2):

You go to her father , and ask for Engagement (Khutbaa) to his daughter. You get to know her (with the supervision of her family) by this engagement . You don't flirt or speak romantically , you don't touch , you don't see her without hijab. you don't be alone with her .  Then you marry her if you want her , or  cut the relationship if she is not the one.